# Is it possible to set a timeout after a user clicks a HTML Link?

Tags: javascript, html

javascript newbie here, but I was wondering if it is possible to set a timeout after a user clicks a HTML Link, now I was wondering this because I am making a simple maths game, and it uses the alert method, which means that once a user clicks the link, the page in which the link is placed, is still visible in the background, which doesn't look very good. I was looking around and found a method called "window.setTimeout" and I was wondering if I could tie that method to the anchor tag in the HTML Code. Thanks :)

My Code: (Note the game isn't finished yet :) )

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Maths Game 0.1 Beta</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var num1 = prompt("What is 2x10?");
    if (num1 == '20') {
      alert("Nice Job!");

    } else {
      alert("Oh well, try again.");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Search Google for "javascript adding a timeout to a link"

Comment: You can't interrupt a `prompt()` with a timeout. You need to use an HTML dialog for this.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for replying, never had people reply to me this quickly on any forum board.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you have a `<a id="foo" href="#"> </a>` in your HTML, once could do

```
document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // do stuff
    }, 5000); // triggers the callback after 5s
};
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried most of these methods and had the same problem, after testing it, clicking the link, the prompts don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
     <head>
     <title> Maths Game 0.1 Beta</title>
     </head>
     <body>
     <a href="#" onclick="setTimeout('question()', 5000);">First Question</a>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function question(){
     var num1 = prompt("What is 2x10?");
     if (num1=='20'){
         alert ("Nice Job!");
     }
        else {alert ("Oh well, try again.");}   
     }
     </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/h7xpxzgg/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to actually load a new page and *then* have the alert pop up, right?

Well, timeouts won't run once the user has left your page.

But there are at least two ways to do what you're asking:

1. Fake the page.
   You can include everything that would be on the "next page" on the current page, but hide it with `display:none`, and once the user clicks your link, you first make the content of the original page invisible, then make the content of the "next" page visible, and then show the alert.
2. Pass a value to the next page, and do the alert there.
   Since this is all client-side, I suggest using [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location), like

   On the current page:

   ```
   <script>
   document.write('<a href="next_page.html#' + prompt('What is 2x10?') + '">Next page</a>');
   </script>
   ```

   On the next page:

   ```
   <script>
   var num1 = window.location.hash.substr(1); // To get rid of the #
   if(num1 == '20')
   {
       alert("Nice Job!");
   }
   else
   {
       alert("Oh well, try again.");
   }  
   </script>
   ```